# Tool to run tasks in one of two machines if one is not available

Tags: windows, scheduled-tasks, scheduling

I have two servers in Windows Server A and Server B. Both of them are the tasks defined in the Task scheduler. Is there a tool or a program that allows automatic execution of tasks on one server only where:

1. One of the servers is unavailable.
2. One of the servers started earlier than the other.

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Not that I'm aware of. You'd need to script on one to control that. IE server 1 checks for server 2. If its up it checks its uptime. If its uptime is greater than server 1, it does nothing. Server 2 does the same.

You may run into a situation with a network blip that both and up processing.  You can check remote boot times via wmi [Find last boot up time of remote Windows computers using WMI](http://www.powershelladmin.com/wiki/Find_last_boot_up_time_of_remote_Windows_computers_using_WMI)

```
PS C:\>$LastBootUpTime = Get-WmiObject Win32_OperatingSystem -Comp winxpssd | Select -Exp LastBootUpTime
PS C:\> [System.Management.ManagementDateTimeConverter]::ToDateTime($LastBootUpTime)
```

Powershell 3 has Get-CimInstance where you can use -ComputerName
[Powertip get the las boot tim with powershell.aspx](http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2013/03/27/powertip-get-the-last-boot-time-with-powershell.aspx)

Get-CimInstance docs can be found [here](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/%5Clibrary/jj590758(v=wps.630).aspx)

```
Get-CimInstance -ClassName win32_operatingsystem | select csname, lastbootuptime
```